# How do you update eclipse (4.19.0) on mac?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using eclipse with a java maven project for a long time without issue, but then it randomly started giving errors (e.g. when looking for references of a method) requiring restarting eclipse.  Now it wont work at all, so I want to try updating eclipse.  Below is the error I get:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Java Search".
Cannot invoke 
"org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeBinding.kind()" because "receiverType" is null
```

The official instructions seem to be wrong (for my version at least)

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F

It says "Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites"|

However, under window, I dont have preferences.

I do have help->"Check for Updates" which waits a long time, then comes up with a list of items and says "the operation cannot be completed" and "cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency" under details.

help->"install new software" has "work with type or select a site", but I have no idea what to put in here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Reinstall latest version keeping your data (projects)?

Comment: On macs the Preferences is in the Eclipse menu rather than Windows. Personally I always install a new version from scratch rather than upgrading. That still preserves your workspace.

Comment: I've got the same error, and can't get it resolved with a reinstallation